# multiple string comparison in a single if statement shell script using OR gate

Tags: unix, if-statement, logical-operators

I am trying to compare the value stored in string variable with three different possible values and if any of them does not matches then trying to throw error, in a single if statement using the logical operator OR. But everytime I am getting error even though the value stored in the variable is same as one of the possible value. Please find the snippets I tried.

```
    if [[ "$TYPE" != "LOCAL" || "$TYPE" != "REMOTE" || "$TYPE" != "BOTH" ]]; then
        echo -e "\n\tINCORRECT OR NULL ARGUMENTS PASSED. PLEASE VERIFY AND CORRECT THE USAGE MENTIONED AS BELOW: \n"
        Usage
        exit 1
    fi


    if [[ "$TYPE" != "LOCAL" ]] || [["$TYPE" != "REMOTE" ]] || [["$TYPE" != "BOTH" ]]; then
        echo -e "\n\tINCORRECT OR NULL ARGUMENTS PASSED. PLEASE VERIFY AND CORRECT THE USAGE MENTIONED AS BELOW: \n"
        Usage
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: Just want to know why  none of the above is working. I referred at many places and found they are correct. This small issue is freaking me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use AND (&&) instead. See:

OR:

```
irb(main):002:0> true || true || false
=> true

irb(main):003:0> true || true || true
=> true

irb(main):004:0> false || false || false
=> false
```

AND:

```
irb(main):005:0> true && true && false
=> false

irb(main):006:0> true && true && true
=> true

irb(main):007:0> false && false && false
=> false
```

Using ruby just for demonstration